# Ground Symbol, which one I should use?

Tags: signal, ground, grounding, earth

I normally use this symbol [image] in my schematic as my signal ground.
But recently my manager asked me to use this symbol instead [image] because the one that I am using is the earth ground and I should use the signal ground instead.

I checked the IEC 60417 standard, which says this [image] is the symbol for signal ground.
Then I started checking big companies' data sheets, especially their evaluation boards, and I found that all of them use the first symbol. I am talking about Analog Devices, Intel, TI, Qualcomm, Cypress, etc. Even Altium uses this [image] as its signal ground in its tutorial videos.

My question is: why do these giant companies use this symbol [image] as their common ground?

Comment: Most engineers, it seems, aren't terribly consistent with it, and use the symbols interchangeably. I only bother to use specific ones when I need to distinguish two or more grounds.

Comment: @ThePhoton 's answer is the right one, of course, as far as jobs go! When I was at University in the USA over 20 years ago, we used your preferred symbol for all grounds. Now, I've started using the triangle for signal, the 3 bars for earth, and a third symbol for chassis... There are a lot of older docs, as you pointed out, and so I doubt anyone would be confused by any of them.

Comment: My  personal pet peeve.   Use the right symbols people!!!!   Those 3 types of "ground" aren't the same things at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ISO/IEC Power/Ground Symbol in schematics?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/616430/iso-iec-power-ground-symbol-in-schematics)

Comment: I normally use the triangle for ground, and I add an "A" for analog ground, "D" for digital ground, and "P" for power ground. The other symbols are reserved for chassis and earth grounds. That may be just my personal preference.

Comment: related: [Help me understand the relationship between positive, negative, neutral and ground in AC and DC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/55350)

Comment: You’re referring to a completely irrelevant standard. **IEC 60417** specifies symbols _for printing on equipment_. It’s **IEC 60617** that specifies circuit diagram symbols.

Answer (score 23):

Whether to follow the IEC spec or some other convention is up to each company individually. If your boss says to use the IEC one, use the IEC one.

Comment: +1 - this is not electronics issue, it is a workplace issue. If company policy says you do it X way, then you do it X way (unless it is safety hazard or illegal). You don't have to *agree* with your boss, you just have to *do it*.

Answer (score 18):

> Ground Symbol, which one I should use?

The following would be of help to decide which symbol would be appropriate.

**1. Earth ground**

[image]

This is related to protective earthing of mains operated electrical equipment. It is an installation of earthing conductors that connect non-current carrying metallic parts such as structures, enclosures, guards etc. to an 'earth pit' or a 'ground stake'.

In the event of such metallic parts getting electrified during fault conditions, the fault current flowing through the earth to the neutral would trip MCBs / GFCIs and thereby safeguard personnel, coming in contact with the equipment, from the risk of electric shock.

**2. Chassis ground**

[image]

Chassis ground implies connections to the chassis of electrical equipment in order that it provides a return path for current or serves as a shield.

Chassis ground and earth ground may be interconnected to facilitate protective earthing.

**3. Signal ground**

[image]

Signal ground is a connection to the positive or the negative rail enabling one or the other to serve as the reference point.

Comment: The “Chassis” symbol is _obsolete_ in circuit diagrams (IEC 60617). The symbol is only available for printing on equipment (IEC 60417).